# Android studio isn't generating the auto generating files

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

When i started to try firebase authentication for my app, i want google sign in but for google sign requires the "default_web_client_id" and this part is auto generated by android studio, but now when i want to generate it does't generating. It was working fine before. I have tried everything from cache removing and upgradation and all. I have reviewed all my code and there is nothing that can do this.

Here you can see that the code that is on right is suppose to auto generate on left sides res(generated) folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved the problem. In android studio ,
Step 1:   **Go to File -> Invalidate caches/restart**
Step 2: Update your gradle version, Go to your build.gradle(project) and change the version "

```
dependency{ classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version" }
```